# iOS SwiftUI - Cannot pass function of type '() async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
TextField("search", text: $searchText)
    .accentColor(Color("ClickableLink"))
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .focused($focusedField, equals: .field)
    .onAppear {
        self.focusedField = .field
    }
    .onSubmit {
        loadinglayout = true

        do {
            try await getMemes()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I get

"Cannot pass function of type '() async -> Void' to parameter expecting synchronous function type"

inside onSubmit.

So far the

```
do
```

method solved this kind of issues, why not here? I have absolutely no idea what else I could try

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call an `async` method from a synchronous method. `onSubmit` is synchronous, while `getMemes` is async.

You need to wrap `async` methods in a `Task` if you want to call them from a synchronous context.

```
.onSubmit {
    loadinglayout = true
    Task {
        do {
            try await getMemes()
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are calling async function inside button

```
Button {
         Task{
               await fetchData()
             }
       } label: {
               Text("Refresh Time")
       }
```

it will wait for function to return data.